# how to specify only start index in LIMIT in MySQL select query?

Tags: mysql

I want to select the records from the table starting from 3rd row. How this can achieved with LIMIT?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: The thing is: it's easier for other people to find the answer to something if we check the answers to our questions and select the right one.

Comment: Click the tick icon underneath the answer's score. The tick will turn green - you've accepted that answer.

Answer (score 12):

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset  up to the end of the
>    result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.
>    This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

Answer (score 1):

[Like this:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 2, 18446744073709551615;
```

(The offset is zero-based)

Comment: -1, you've edited this answer several times with multiple incorrect answers.

Comment: Actually it's not, you need to put the word "Limit" in it. (Edit: now fixed)

Answer (score 1):

i am giving syntax

SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
[WHERE Clause]
[OFFSET M ][LIMIT N]